# Highcharts - zooming to single day pushes column off graph

Tags: highcharts

When zooming to a single date on a column graph with two series one of the columns gets pushed outside of the chart drawing area.

You can see it in action here http://alfred.stlouisfed.org/graph/?g=Sfs

and here is a screenshot of the dev inspector highlighting where it appears off the graph edge

[image: dev inspector screenshot]

Has anyone seen this before? Or have any idea what settings may be affecting it? It works okay if you zoom out to two dates, but unfortunetly the product owners are insisting on only showing one date.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Every two columns of your data is for `three months`, not for a `day`. The chart selects a starting point for every timerange and sticks to it. If you zoom in the empty area in the scale of a day you will see nothing. So correct your data, or your scale of zooming.

Comment: Its for 3 months because it's quarterly data. What do you mean scale the zoom?

Comment: I said correct your scale of zooming, meaning don't zoom more than three months or this will happen